# How to properly merge on a busy highway?

Tags: legal, driving

While merging freeway with speed limit of 100 km/hr. I accelerate to catch up merging speed of 100 km/hr, driver behind me almost touching my tail. Vehicles on freeway are not letting me merge because tailgating mode (continuously occupying lane) and merging lane ending up. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it stands this is asking for driving advice and the legality of road practices. Maybe Law.SE could help?

Comment: @Joernano then pretty much all driving questions are off topic. Voting to keep

Comment: Is your concern more about the fact that the lane you are trying to merge into is head to tail due to the tailgating in **that** lane rather than your own lane?

Comment: It seems like, if this is on-topic, so is *every* other driver's education question. I don't know whether it's on-topic or not, but I do think closing it would *not* imply that all other driving questions are also off-topic; for example, I think the "In Russia, what does the CTON sign mean?" question is much more clearly on-topic than this question.

Comment: @JonathanReez I see no precise geolocalisation for this question. Nor do I see an actual Travel need. The way it is phrased makes it sound like a question one would ask to one's driving instructor in one's home country. Doesn't feel like [an on-topic Travel question to me](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This does not make all driving question off-topic here.

Comment: Where in the world is this happening? For example in Germany, traffic coming from the ramp has to yield to traffic on the freeway.

Comment: @JoErNanO adding "in the US" would make this travel related, but the answer is almost the same for most regulated highways

Comment: You forgot the most important thing in your question. Put on your blinkers! Depending on where you are, most people will make space for you.

Answer (score 7):

Easy. You slowly brake and wait for space in the main lanes of traffic. Should the driver behind you crash into your car, he would be considered at-fault in pretty much every jurisdiction out there as tailgating is strictly prohibited.

Another thing you might do is flash your brake lights a few times to indicate your intentions. Hopefully this should signal the car behind you to back off.

Comment: The only problem you can wait veeery long time until the big enough wait space appear.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo depends on your driving skills. There are almost always holes you can fit into.

Comment: but the hole between cars driving 100 kmph need to be really big if you accelerate from null with a regular car, and with high traffic, it might be a few minutes or even a dozen...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo you can usually use the emergency lane to accelerate. Other drivers will then slow down a bit as they don't want to crash. It's mostly an issue for novice drivers.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Not sure that's relevant; in the US when entering a freeway, I've never seen any merge where you weren't expected to yield to the traffic on the freeway.  So you stop and wait as long as it takes.

Comment: @Jonathan You just got yourself a really expensive ticket at least in Germany if you use the emergency lane in that situation. And if you try to force your way into the lane and have an accident, you'll be at fault (to be fair, at that point that expensive ticket from earlier will be the least of your worries).

Comment: @Voo you also get a heave ticket for tailgating so OP's situation is unlikely to happen there

Comment: Jonathan, This is my concern 1. forcing into lane will cause collision 2.Moving on emergency lane i can get ticket 3. Applying brake to avoid moving emergency lane will result rear ending.(getting knocked from behind with this speed will seriously injure the occupants). What should i do in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

Try to not get influenced by other drivers who are breaking the rules.
It's 'his problem' he is tailgating and he will be at fault if he hits you.

Driving a Smart people often do not want to let me get in front of them (has the reputation of slow car because it in fact does not accelerate that fast.) and what I do is turn on my signals a little early*, making people aware that I'm planning to merge soon. If you see a space coming up behind the car next to you, brake a little.

If there truly is no space, or the cars have the option to go to a lane on the left to make room for you, try to make a slight movement to the left and see what the cars do. If they brake or start to switch lanes, move in.

It's never good to enforce your place on the road, but if doing so is the safest option (or at least safer than ending up beyond the end of the merging lane) you should do it, with caution.

*This was a tip my driving instructor gave me because I was scared to merge. You should wait with turning on your signals until you actually plan to move, but in practice it's often much safer in these situations to do so before you want to move.

Comment: "try to make a slight movement to the left and see what the cars do" - like panic and swerve to the other lane or hit the brakes and causing a collision. If you have to do something that's not really allowed, my preference would be to use a few meters (as little as possible) of the emergency lane rather than scaring other drivers into thinking I might not have seen them.

Comment: @CompuChip maybe I didn't explain it well enough but I mean driving more to the left of your own lane, not coming onto their lane. If they are not budging, they will not budge if you enter the emergency lane either, that does not fix the problem at all.

Comment: "You should wait with turning on your signals until you actually plan to move": I disagree. In Europe, the norm is that you start signalling even before you reach the freeway, to wake up the freeway drivers and remind them that they might need to make room for you. It works very well -- in 30+ years of driving, I have had to stop on the entrance ramp exactly once.

Comment: @TonyK I live in Europe (the Netherlands), just passed my exam months ago and was told you can not turn your signals on until you are actually planning to move. Not if you want to move but can't. This was told to me by my instructor and again by my examinator when I signalled 'too early'

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: Are you sure that's what they said? That would certainly apply to a car _already on_ the freeway, but in my opinion it is terrible advice to a car _approaching_ the freeway.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 I was told the opposite (by an instructor, not so long ago). In In this situation the signal indicates the intention.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.motoringassist.com/motoring-advice/road-safety/road-safety-general/motorway-safety/#joining_and_leaving_the_motorway): "While still on the slip road, you should use your right indicator to draw attention to your vehicle and to your intention to merge with the traffic on the motorway."

Comment: -1; in the US a merge lane (which ends) you're expected to yield, which means if you can't get on, you stop and wait until something opens up.  Whether people actually do that or not isn't the point, that's what the laws say.  I don't think traffic already on the freeway has to do anything to actually allow you to merge in most places.

Comment: @TonyK This does not specifically apply the Dutch guidelines, I imagined it would be the same through all EU. I am very sure because I had multiple discussions about this with my instructor.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 to add a UK perspective, I was taught to indicate 3-6 seconds before you start the manoeuvre to signal your intention to start moving, and on a slip lane you indicate before reaching the actual junction.

Comment: @JaneDoe In Germany/Austria you have to blink at least 3 times before being legally allowed to change lanes. Apart from that, the law specifies that you should signal to notify other drivers of your intent to change lanes (how early this should happen depends on speed and other situation though). See e.g. BGH VRS 25, 264 where it was found that with 30km/h you should blink 5 seconds before changing lanes.

Comment: [Link to the decision in German](http://www.gerichtsentscheidungen.berlin-brandenburg.de/jportal/portal/t/2aar/bs/10/page/sammlung.psml?pid=Dokumentanzeige&showdoccase=1&js_peid=Trefferliste&documentnumber=1&numberofresults=1&fromdoctodoc=yes&doc.id=KORE503682004&doc.part=L&doc.price=0.0#focuspoint)

Comment: @Voo: That has nothing to do with freeways or motorways or Autobahnen! Rominter Allee is a two-way cobbled street in suburban Berlin.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: Are you absolutely sure that the Dutch guidelines apply to joining a motorway from a slip road? Because if so, they are dangerous and should be ignored.

Comment: @TonyK The explanation given isn't limited to small city streets (which would be pretty weird - so you have to signal for 5 seconds before changing lanes in the city, but you can immediately change on a highway when going 130?): "Rechtzeitig ist das Zeichen, wenn sich der Verkehr auf das Abbiegen einstellen kann. Dafür ist weniger die Entfernung zum Abbiegepunkt maßgebend, als vielmehr die Zeit zwischen Anzeigebeginn und Abbiegen unter Berücksichtigung der Fahrtgeschwindigkeit". I don't see why that guidance wouldn't apply on highways either.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 "You should wait with turning on your signals until you actually plan to move": this could be a misunderstanding about English, not how to drive. Your *intention* or *plan* to join the main carriageway starts *as soon as you turn onto the slipway* - there isn't any other reason why you would be driving on the slipway! If you put your indicator on *as *soon as you are on the slipway*, that is one less thing you will have to do later when you have other things to worry about, like merging into a small gap between other cars.

Comment: @alephzero Obviously I'm trying my best to explain things in proper English even though I'm not a native speaker. Turning on your signal right away has no use at all as it will not alert people on other lanes effectively.

Answer (score 1):

If vehicles are driving at 100km/h (= 60 mph) and the space between all of them is *less than the length of your car*, then they are all homicidal maniacs.

Even assuming the are all "tailgating", their minimum reaction time will be about half a second, and at 100km/h they will travel about 14 meters in that distance. An average sized compact car is about 5 meters long, or less.

Matching your speed with the other traffic and slotting into a gap is mostly about confidence. Most other drivers are intelligent enough to know that is what you want to do (why else would you be driving on the slip lane?) and won't *aggressively* stop you doing it - but unless you car is displaying "learner" plates, they won't give you *more* room than you need.

What the car behind you on the slip lane does is not your problem. Applying the basic principle of "don't drive so fast that you can't stop within the distance you can see is clear", insurance companies usually take the view that in a rear-end collision, the rear driver is automatically the one who is at fault.

But remember the driver behind you is probably planning to move into the *next* gap behind the one that you take, and so of course he/she will be driving fairly close behind you. If you hesitate or slow down, then *you* are potentially causing a hazardous situation *by doing something unexpected*.

Comment: Your answer is pretty comprehensive.